# Add a static prefix to everylogged message with slf4j

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

Is there a way to add a static (not context dynamic) prefix to all logged messages when using slf4j *without* altering the formatting of the underlying logging framework? To be clear, that means that using MDC is not an option because this would need to be reflected in the formatting configuration of the underlying framework.

Is there another option than creating a custom wrapper for the slf4j logger and using it wherever I would normally simply initialize a slf4j logger?

```
public class CustomLogger {

  private final String prefix = "custom-prefix";

  private final Logger logger;

  public CustomLogger(Class clazz) {
    logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz);
  }

  public void info(String info) {
    logger.info (prefix + info);
  }

  // other methods...

}
```

If some context is needed: I am working in an environment where multiple plugins run on a core  application. Within such a plugin I would like to add the plugin's name as a prefix to logged messages.

Comment: Even though some time has passed, I had the same problem and found this mailing list entry quite helpful: http://mailman.qos.ch/pipermail/slf4j-user/2013-May/001343.html

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your calls in another method that does a String.format(...) on the passed in String. Your formatter will have your static string, and will place the logging string somewhere before, within, or after that, before passing it onto the actual logger method.

Comment: So basically you recommend to use a wrapper as shown above? The question of string concatenation vs. `String.format(...)` is implementation detail - my concern was if usage of a wrapper class is the _right way_ to enforce the prefix with slf4j.

Comment: A wrapper method is more flexible than hard-coding it in your logging pattern, which is your other choice. If you define the Loggers and Appenders and all logger properties in your code (instead of just reconfiguring the default Loggers) you could also do it there. At the end of the day the String needs to be in your Pattern or in the String passed to the logging method.